# why i already import this Error: "App\cat" not found

Tags: laravel

There is a relationship between the 2 models. And I want to display category name instead of category_id in show.bade.php. I am getting a this error.

**Post model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\cat;---- this is my cat model

class post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_name',
        'post_content',
        'name',
        'status',
        'file_path',
        'slug',
        'game_category_id'

    ];
  
 public function cat(){
    return $this->belongsTo(cat::class);
 }
```

**cat model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\post;------this is my post model

class cat extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'cats';
     protected $fillable = ['name','slug'];


    public function post(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

There is a relationship between the 2 models. And I want to display category name instead of category_id in show.blade.php. I am getting a this error.

**Blade.php**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$post->id}}</th>
      <td><img src="{{asset('img/') . '/' .$post->file_path}}" width="100px " height="50px" class="img_table"></td>
       <td>{{$post->post_name}}</td>
      <td>{{$post->name}}</td>
      <td>  
        @if(strcmp($post->status , 'Published') == 0)
            <div class="btn btn-success">{{$post->status}}</div>
        @else
        <div class="btn btn-warning">{{$post->status}}</div>
        @endif </td>
         <td>{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->slug}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->cat->name}}</td>
      <td><a href="" class="btn btn-info"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="/delete/{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

$post->cat->name is this right way to call cat name instead of category id

**Post Controller**

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\post;

use Validator;

  public function list(){
        $posts = Post::with('cat')->get();
        $carbon = Carbon::now();
        return view('layout.show', compact('posts'),['carbon' => $carbon]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 8 the default namespace for models is `App\Models`. So `use App\cat;` should be `use App\Models\cat;`.

But you don't have to specify that since both `post` and `cat` are in the same namespace. You can just get rid of that line and it should still work.

By the way, Laravel's naming convention for models is to use CamelCase. So I'd stick with that unless you have a specific reason not to do so.

Comment: i change App\cat;  to App\Models\cat then i get next error that is , Attempt to read property "name" on null .... <td>{{$post->cat->name}}</td> that is right way to call cat->name

Answer (score 0):

you have to change `App\cat` to `App\Models\cat` this will work...

and next.. that line you write `<td>{{$post->cat->name}}</td>` this will occur error,[`Attempt to read property "name" on null`] you changed to use separate foreach loop..

```
@foreach($post->cat as cat)
    <td>{{$cat->name}}</td>
@endforeach
```

This will work for you ...